# How to find length of a multi-dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you find the length of a multi-dimensional list?

I've come up with a way myself, but is this the only way to find the number of values in a multi-dimensional list?

```
multilist = [['1', '2', 'Ham', '4'], ['5', 'ABCD', 'Foo'], ['Bar', 'Lu', 'Shou']]
counter = 0
for minilist in multilist:
    for value in minilist:
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```

I'm pretty sure there is a much simpler way to find the length of a multi-dimensional list, but len(list) does not work, as it only gives the number of lists inside. Is there a more efficient method than this?

Comment: With Python, there always is.

Comment: Are the lists restricted to 2 levels or can they be deeper?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
sum(len(x) for x in multilist)
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternative to @mgilson's solution

```
sum(map(len, multilist))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of items in any n-dimensional list then you need to use a recursive function like this:

```
def List_Amount(List):
    return _List_Amount(List)
def _List_Amount(List):
    counter = 0
    if isinstance(List, list):
        for l in List:
            c = _List_Amount(l)
            counter+=c
        return counter
    else:
        return 1
```

This will  return the number of items in the list no matter the shape or size of your list

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative (it's this or watch missed math lectures...)

```
def getLength(element):
    if isinstance(element, list):
        return sum([getLength(i) for i in element])
    return 1
```

This allows different degrees of *'multi-dimensionality'* (if that were a word) to coexist.

eg:

```
>>> getLength([[1,2],3,4])
4
```

Or, to allow different collection types

```
def getLength(element):
    try:
        element.__iter__
        return sum([getLength(i) for i in element])
    except:
        return 1
```

eg:

```
>>> getLength([ 1, 2, (1,3,4), {4:3} ])
6
>>> getLength(["cat","dog"])
2
```

(Noting that although strings are iterable, they do not have the __iter__ method-wrapper and so will not cause any issues...)

Comment: Just a heads up that the last version of this code will break if there are any strings in the data structure, since `"A"` is iterable, and it's lone member is also `"A"` (leading to an error when you hit the recursion limit). I suppose it will also recurse infinitely if you create a list that contains a reference to itself, but that's not likely to happen by accident. Also, you won't correctly count items that are in containers that are values of dictionaries (though you will count the values in tuple keys).

Comment: I don't think it should. My version of python (2.7.2) raises an error for "string".__iter__

Comment: Hmm, how odd. `str.__iter__` does exist in Python 3, and even in Python 2, calling `iter("foo")` works just fine.